# The report has no tables (DataTable -> Crystal Report)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to crystal reporting. Is there a way to add a datatable that i made to a crystal report sa datasource?

I've used this datatable to a datagridview, is it possible to use that datatable as source for crystal report?

```
DataAccess datax = new DataAccess();
DataSet ds = new DataSet("dataset");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn property, minimum, result, maximum, remarks;

    public ReportingForm(string resin_type, string resin_code, string batch_num)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datax.initialize();

        AnalysisReport analysis_rep = new AnalysisReport();

        property = new DataColumn();
        minimum = new DataColumn();
        result = new DataColumn();
        maximum = new DataColumn();
        remarks = new DataColumn();

        property.ColumnName = "Property";
        minimum.ColumnName = "Minimum";
        result.ColumnName = "Result";
        maximum.ColumnName = "Maximum";

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { property, minimum, result, maximum, remarks });

        initialize_data(resin_type, resin_code, batch_num); //sets the rows

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        analysis_rep.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

        crpt.ReportSource = analysis_rep;
    }
```

in the line `analysis_rep.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);` it throws an error that says "The report has no tables"

I also tried `analysis_rep.SetDataSource(dt);` where I tried setting the data source as a data table, same results.

ds.Tables.Count = 1

Comment: did you try this analysis_rep.SetDataSource(ds); ? also are you sure you are getting any data back means you do have data in ds or dt?

Comment: I did just now. Same results.

Comment: are you adding the tables to dataset before filling it or after filling it? cause i don't see when is it filing with data or i am missing something?. In any case, make sure you are adding the table to dataset before filling it..

Comment: Yes, I've seen this '.fill' code, but not sure how to use it. I've seen it mostly used with sql data adapters which in this case I do not use. There's no filling happening here. But this works in datagridview

Comment: what do you mean by works in datagridview? it doesn't throw any error in gridview or it shows data in gridview?

Comment: under initialize_data() it adds the necessary rows. when i use datagridview.DataSource(dt);, it shows the table without any errors.